# My Database wrapper doesn't let me use fetchAll or any other PDO functions

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I'm trying to loop through a result set and print out the values of the rows using PDO with my PHP database wrapper that I made using a tutorial. When I'm using PDO functions like fetchAll(); or fetch(); I get fatal errors.

I'm just curious how I can do this with the code I've provided. I can use the code below to easily implement insert, updates to data etc but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to just loop and print. Any help would be amazing thanks.

The I need help with is the getOffers function in the bottom block of code.

I have a DB.php file:

```
    class DB {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
            $_query,
            $_error = false,
            $_results,
            $_count = 0;

    private function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' .Config::get('mysql/host'). ';dbname=' .Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $x = 1;
            if(count($params)) {
                foreach($params as $param) {
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }

            if($this->_query->execute()) {
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            } else {
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
        if(count($where) === 3) {
            $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

            $field = $where[0];
            $operator = $where[1];
            $value = $where[2];

            if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                $sql = $sql = "{$action} FROM `{$table}` WHERE {$field} {$operator} '{$value}'";;
                if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function get($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
    }
    //deletes items from the database
    public function delete($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);
    }

    public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {
        //check if fields has any data
        if(count($fields)) {
            $keys = array_keys($fields);
            $values = null;
            $x = 1;

            foreach($fields as $field) {
                $values .= "?";
                //check if x is less than the count of fields
                if($x < count($fields)) {
                    $values .= ', ';
                }
                $x++;
            }

            $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";

            if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function update($table, $id, $fields) {
        $set = '';
        $x = 1;

        foreach($fields as $name => $value) {
            $set .= "{$name} = ?";
            if($x < count($fields)) {
                $set .= ', ';
            }
            $x++;
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE `id` = {$id}";

        if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function results() {
        return $this->_results;
    }

    public function first() {
        return $this->results()[0];

    }

    public function error() {
        return $this->_error;
    }

    public function count() {
        return $this->_count;
    }
}
```

And I have Offer.php:

```
  <?php
  class Offer {
    private $_db,
            $_data;

    public function __construct() {
      $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
    }

    public function createOffer($fields = array()) {
      //If the offer is not entered into the database
      if(!$this->_db->insert('offers', $fields)) {
        throw new Exception('There was a Problem creating the offer.');
      }
    }

    public function getOffers() {
      $offers = $this->_db->get('offers', array('address', '=', 'Los Angeles'));
$result = $offers->fetchAll();
  print_r($result);


  }

  }
?>
```

Comment: What fatal errors do you get?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB::fetchAll()

I have updated the code above to show where I'm getting this fatal error. Thanks.

Comment: You need to add the fetchAll() function to your class. It currently only belongs to DB's private $_query variable.

Comment: Mandatory: [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)

Comment: @aynber should I just move the function into DB.php? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes. You can name the function getAll, just like you have `get`.

Comment: @aynber doesn't my get function already 'Get All' already? Thats what I was trying to utilize in the first place

Comment: I think if you don't pass anything in for $where, your get will fail

Comment: It doest fail, when I var_dump on $offers I can see all the data I need, I just want to put it in an array and print it

Answer (score 0):

It seems in Offer.php it should be

```
$result = $offers->results();
```

not

```
$result = $offers->fetchAll();
```

Comment: thanks I thought this myself at first, my _results variable is private so when I try to access it from Offer.php I get thrown an error. Should I move the function into DB.php?

Comment: Having another look at your code I have updated the answer. Though I would make variables `public`. Otherwise this `return false;` from `action` would bite you in the back when you expect DB class return value.

Comment: Will it not have security implications by making those variables public?

Comment: Theoretically, ill-coded script might corrupt the results of it's own previous SQL call, but I would be much more worried with the possibility of SQL injection through `$where` parameters array that is completely open at the moment.

Comment: Try (or rather don't) to `get('offers', array('1=2; drop table offers; select * from dual where 1', '=', '2'))`